# Chromatic polynomial for hyper cube

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, chromatic-polynomial

Does anyone know the chromatic polynomial of the hyper cube graph Q4?
I need this to verify that my listing of a subset of all DAG's on the 4-cube is correct.

Any help greatly appreciated,
      JC

Comment: Also posted on Math.SE: [The chromatic polynomial of the hyper cube graph $Q_4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2330016)

Answer (score 6):

This is what [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=chromatic+polynomial+tesseract+graph) says:

[image: Q4]

And here it is in TeX:
$$
 (x-1)
   x
   \left(x^{14}-3
   1 x^{13}+465
   x^{12}-4471
   x^{11}+30793
   x^{10}-160807
   x^9+\\657229
   x^8-2137667
   x^7+5564285
   x^6-11536667
   x^5+\\18740317
   x^4-23081607
   x^3+20308039
   x^2-11372201
   x+3040575\right)
$$

Comment: The polynomial is also given (but not in factored form) at http://oeis.org/A158348 (down in the MAPLE section).

Comment: I greatly appreciate the answer, and so does my colleague. Both of us are math PhD, but not experts in graph theory. I first posted in a more general forum, but my question was put on hold. I thought the reason was that the question was of research character rather than a student's question. The answer has already been tremendously useful for a group, including students. Perhaps someone could explain what's going on.